# Why need to pass dispatch to useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTodo());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Why need to pass `dispatch` to useEffect dependency?
It is different from writing

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTodo());
  }, []);
```

Comment: The first one will execute each time the value of dispatch changes, the second one will only execute 1 time on component mount

Comment: Could you be more specific than "need"? Are you referencing an error that is coming from your linter or does omitting `dispatch` result in bugs?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime we need to optimize performance by skipping few effects.
In some cases, cleaning up or applying the effect after every render might create a performance problem. In class components, we can solve this by writing an extra comparison with prevProps or prevState inside componentDidUpdate:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.count !== this.state.count) {
        document.title = `You clicked ${this.state.count} times`;
    }
}
```

This requirement is common enough that it is built into the useEffect Hook API. You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an optional second argument to useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
}, [count]); // Only re-run the effect if count changes
```

In the example above, we pass [count] as the second argument. What does this mean? If the count is 5, and then our component re-renders with count still equal to 5, React will compare [5] from the previous render and [5] from the next render. Because all items in the array are the same (5 === 5), React would skip the effect. That’s our optimization.

When we render with count updated to 6, React will compare the items in the [5] array from the previous render to items in the [6] array from the next render. This time, React will re-apply the effect because 5 !== 6. If there are multiple items in the array, React will re-run the effect even if just one of them is different.

This also works for effects that have a cleanup phase:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
        setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
        ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
}, [props.friend.id]); // Only re-subscribe if props.friend.id changes
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the value of `dispatch` is either coming from `useReducer` or `react-redux`. In the first case of `useReducer` hook, `react` guarantees that it will return the **same function** (same reference at each render), therefore adding it to the dependency list will not affect your dispatch call.

As for `react-redux`, I think its safe to assume that it returns the same `dispatch` function as well.

Therefore, your `useEffect` hook will fire once and when and not on any subsequent renders.

Please note that this is only because the same `dispatch` is returned at each render. The same wouldn't happen for any arbitrary variable unless it is wrapped with `useCallback`/`useMemo`.

In a nutshell, anytime even if one of the values in your dependency list changes, `useEffect` fires again. Since `dispatch` doesn't change it doesn't run again. React uses `Object.is` to compare values.

From react docs:

> React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the useEffect
> or useCallback dependency list.

The same goes for dispatch returned by `useReducer`.

This would be easier to understand if you know how hooks work behind the scene, if you are interested I wrote a blog post simplifying the topic.

https://rohitpotato.hashnode.dev/how-react-implements-usestate-and-useeffect-internally-a-simplified-overview-1